# How to install the latest version of GCC on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, gcc, installation

I've tried googling but it all just confuses me.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can install [version 7.2.0 of gcc](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gcc.rb) pretty easily.

Follow the installation instructions on https://brew.sh/. After installing, run the following command in your terminal (Terminal.app):

```
brew install gcc
```

That will install version 7.2.0 using the [current gcc forumla](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gcc.rb) which [appears to currently be the latest version](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/).

Comment: I'm doing this right now before I saw your answer. How do I make XCode use that version instead of the original version? I'm kinda drifting here, but is it handled automatically?